# Shopware 6 How to disable ESLint during watch scripts?

Tags: shopware6

I am trying to use `bin/watch-administration.sh` but due to linting errors in third party plugins the compilation fails.

How can I disable ESLint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to disable ESLint during either `bin/watch-administration.sh` or `bin/watch-storefront.sh` the environment variable `ESLINT_DISABLE` can be set to `true` in the projects `.env` file:

```
ESLINT_DISABLE=true
```